# az aks nodepool delete

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I use the command `az aks nodepool delete -g $myresource --cluster-name $mycluster --name $mypool` to delete node pools in aks, but this command kill any running job. I am trying to optimize azure AKS cots, and some times it would be useful to schedule `az aks nodepool delete`.

Is it any way to schedule `az aks nodepool delete` so a node pool will be deleted after a job is finished?

Comment: It would be better to scale down the node pools and not delete the whole group

Comment: @AmitBaranes the resource group `$myresource` has two node pools, the one that is a must for az aks, and one that I create when I need to run things on GPUs. So, by using the command in my question, I only delete the node pool with the GPU and not the whole group

Comment: how do you sure this command kills any running jobs? (just trying to collect more info)

Comment: reading the documentation i saw that there is an optional parameter `--no-wait`, hence I thought that if I do not pass that argument in `az aks nodepool delete`, the node pool will be deleted after the job is done. So, I tested it. I wrote the delete command, without `--no-wait`, while running a job, and the job was killed.

Comment: Which version of azure cli are you running ?

Comment: az version is `2.0.81`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212848/discussion-between-amit-baranes-and-user1571823).

Comment: answer in the chat

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to delete your NodePool that are creating VMs for GPU.

Note that while deleting the AgentPool could be a viable solution, you should look at the newly release feature from AKS which allow User Mode NodePool to be scaled down to 0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-system-pools

With this version of AKS: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/releases/tag/2020-04-13

```
Features
AKS has now introduced a new Mode property for nodepools. This will allow you to set nodepools as System or User nodepools. System nodepools will have additional validations and will be preferred by system pods, while User pool will have more lax validations and can perform additional operations like scale to 0 nodes or be removed from the cluster. Each cluster needs at least one system pool. All details here: https://aka.ms/aks/nodepool/mode
System/User nodepools are available from core CLI version 2.3.1 or greater (or latest preview extension 0.4.43)

Nodepool mode requires API 2020-03-01 or greater

AKS now allows User nodepools to scale to 0.
```

This will allow you to keep the VMSS for your GPU, enable the AutoScaler for the Node Pool and set the minimum node count to 0.

Your GPU nodes will be created when needed (a pod requiring the GPU nodes, should trigger the autoscaler)

Comment: run `az aks upgrade` with the same --version number that you currently have.

Comment: did you mean like this `az aks upgrade --resource-group mygroup --name myname -k 1.14.8` ? I got this message first `The cluster is already on version 1.14.8 and is not in a failed state. No operations will occur when upgrading to the same version if the cluster is not in a failed state.
Since control-plane-only argument is not specified, this will upgrade the control plane AND all nodepools to version 1.14.8. Continue?` and then an error message that I dont have the right permissions

Comment: yeah correct. look at the version of the AKS-Engine, it is written on the VMSS tags that AKS created.